# Unnumbered section not showing title

Tags: sectioning

I've got a custom style that is almost 100% working, but there's a few bugs I've noticed, and this one I can't seem to figure out.

```
\titleformat{\section}
  {\color{cyan}\itshape\LARGE}
  {\llap{\thesection\ }#1}
  {1em}
  {}
  [\titleline{\color{cyan}\titlerule[1pt]}]
```

In my cls file, I've got many bits of code, some of which may be conflicting here. When I make a new empty document based on the `book` class (and appending the above code into the preamble), everything works fine. But with my own class, the section text for an unnumbered section doesn't show.

Here's my cls file:

```
\LoadClass[10pt,letterpaper]{book}
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage

\RequirePackage[
  left=2.25in,
  right=0.75in,
  top=1.25in,
  bottom=1.25in,
  marginparwidth=1.75in,
  marginparsep=.25in,
  asymmetric]{geometry}

\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\RequirePackage{amsthm, amsfonts, amsmath}
\RequirePackage{thmtools}
\RequirePackage{paralist}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\RequirePackage{blindtext, xcolor}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage{mdframed}
\RequirePackage{DejaVuSansCondensed}
\RequirePackage[normalem]{ulem}
\RequirePackage{environ}
\RequirePackage[strict]{changepage}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\RequirePackage{calc}
\RequirePackage{titletoc}

\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} % Set default font

\newcounter{definition}
\setcounter{definition}{0}

%%% Table of Contents ----------------------------------------------------------
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1} % Show only Chapters and Sections

% this stuff moved here for clarity
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro{\appendix}{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand*{\protect\@chapapp}{\protect\appendixname}}}

%%% Change font/color/layout of TOC

% START OF MODIFIED CODE

\contentsmargin{1.5cm} % global right margin, perhaps also global left

\titlecontents{chapter}[3cm] % <-- seems to set some specific left margin
{\color{cyan}\bfseries\LARGE\addvspace{3mm}}
{\makebox[0cm][r]{\@chapapp\hspace{.5em}\thecontentslabel\hspace{.75cm}}}
{} %     ^^^ pretendously zero width box puts its contents in the left margin
{\hfill\makebox[-3cm]{\thecontentspage}}  % 3cm = twice 1.5cm

\titlecontents{section}[3cm] % <-- again this left (additional?) margin
{\color{cyan}\large\itshape\addvspace{3mm}}
{\makebox[0cm][r]{\thecontentslabel\hspace{.75cm}}} % box pushed to the left
{}
{\hfill\makebox[-3cm]{\thecontentspage}}  % 3cm = twice 1.5cm
[\addvspace{0mm}]

% END OF MODIFICATIONS

\makeatother

\makeatletter
% Basically the same as for `\l@section` etc, just `\@nodottedtocline` instead of `\@dottedtcline`:
\newcommand*\l@chapterinfo{\@nodottedtocline{0}{7em}{2.1em}}
\newcommand*\l@sectioninfo{\@nodottedtocline{1}{7em}{2.1em}}

% Copied from the book class macro `\@dottedtocline`. Removed the dots and page number
\def\@nodottedtocline#1#2#3#4#5{%
  \ifnum #1>\c@tocdepth \else
    \vskip \z@ \@plus.2\p@
    {\leftskip #2\relax \rightskip \@tocrmarg \parfillskip -\rightskip
     \parindent #2\relax\@afterindenttrue
     \interlinepenalty\@M
     \leavevmode
     \@tempdima #3\relax
     \advance\leftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip
     {#4}\nobreak
     \leaders\hbox{$\m@th
        \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{\,}\mkern \@dotsep
        mu$}\hfill
     \nobreak
     \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hfil\normalfont \normalcolor }%
     \par}%
  \fi}
\makeatother

%%% New commands to add custom description to Chapter and Section.
\def\chapterinfo#1{%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapterinfo}{%
    \noexpand\numberline{}#1}}%

\def\sectioninfo#1{%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{sectioninfo}{%
    \noexpand\numberline{}#1}}%

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%%% Header and Footer ----------------------------------------------------------

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % sets both header and footer to nothing
\lhead[\textbf{\thepage}\hspace{7mm}\leftmark]{}
\rhead[]{\rightmark\hspace{7mm}\textbf{\thepage}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhfoffset[L]{1.5in}
\fancyhfoffset[R]{0in}

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%%% Sction Styles --------------------------------------------------------------

\makeatletter
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\normalfont\sffamily\Huge\scshape}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {
  \thispagestyle{empty}    % Remove page number on new chapters
  \setcounter{definition}{0}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[yshift=-3cm] at (current page.north west)
      {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw[fill=cyan] (0,-1) rectangle
          (25cm,3cm);
        \draw[fill=cyan] (0,-24) rectangle
          (25cm,-25cm);
        \ifttl@label% <---------------------- Added condition on \ifttl@label
          \node[anchor=west,xshift=.21\paperwidth,yshift=-.01\paperheight,rectangle]
              {\color{white}\LARGE \MakeUppercase{\@chapapp} \Huge\thechapter};
        \fi% <------------------------------- end condition on \ifttl@label
       \end{tikzpicture}
      };
    \end{tikzpicture}\endgraf
    \vskip-.7cm
    \color{cyan}\Huge\raggedright\leftskip-1cm
    \noindent\MakeUppercase{#1}\endgraf
  }
\makeatother
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{10pt}{0pt}{}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\color{cyan}\itshape\LARGE}
  {\llap{\thesection\ }#1}
  {1em}
  {}
  [\titleline{\color{cyan}\titlerule[1pt]}]

\titleformat{\subsection}{\color{cyan}\normalfont\large}{\; #1}{1em}{}

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%%% Custom Environments --------------------------------------------------------

\tikzstyle{cyanbox} = [draw=cyan!50, fill=cyan!10, very thick,
    rectangle, rounded corners, inner sep=10pt, inner ysep=20pt]
\tikzstyle{cyanbox2} = [draw=cyan!50, fill=cyan!10, very thick,
    rectangle, inner sep=10pt, inner ysep=20pt]

\tikzstyle{whitebox} = [draw=cyan!50, fill=white, very thick,
    rectangle, inner sep=10pt, inner ysep=20pt]
\tikzstyle{fancytitle} =[fill=cyan!50, text=white]

\def\thedefinition{\thechapter.\arabic{definition}}
\NewEnviron{definition}[1][Definition]{
  \stepcounter{definition}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node [cyanbox] (box){%
          \begin{minipage}{.9\textwidth}
            \BODY
          \end{minipage}
      };
      \node[fancytitle, right=10pt] at (box.north west) {\bfseries$\bullet$ Definition \thedefinition};
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}}

\NewEnviron{emphasis}{
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node [whitebox] (box){%
          \begin{minipage}{.9\textwidth}
            \BODY
          \end{minipage}
      };
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}}

\NewEnviron{fullwidth}{
  \begin{adjustwidth}{-1.55in}{0in}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node [cyanbox2] (box){%
          \begin{minipage}{\paperwidth - 1.8in}
            \BODY
          \end{minipage}
      };
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
  \end{adjustwidth}}

\def\leftmarginshift{\marginparwidth + \marginparsep}
\def\rightmarginshift{\marginparsep}
\def\bodysize{\textwidth + \rightmarginshift}

\NewEnviron{myimage}[2]{
  \begin{adjustwidth}{-2.0in}{0.25in}
    asdf
    \begin{table}[h]
      \centering
%           \makebox[0pt][c]{\parbox{\textwidth}{%
      \begin{minipage}{2.0in}
        #1.#2
      \end{minipage}
      \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        \BODY
      \end{minipage}
%           }}
    \end{table}
  \end{adjustwidth}
  }

\NewEnviron{notation}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [mybox] (box){%
        \begin{minipage}{.9\textwidth}
          \BODY
        \end{minipage}
    };
    \node[fancytitle, right=10pt] at (box.north west) {\bfseries Notation};
    \end{tikzpicture}}

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%%% Custom Theorems ------------------------------------------------------------

\declaretheoremstyle[
    within=section,
    spaceabove=10mm,
    spacebelow=3mm,
    headfont=\color{cyan}\normalfont,
    notefont=\normalfont,
    bodyfont=\itshape,
    headpunct=\newline\newline,
    %postheadspace={10pt},
    notebraces={}{},
    headformat={%
        \makebox[-15pt][r]{\normalfont\large\NAME\ \NUMBER\;\;\;\;}\setbox0\hbox{\ }\hspace{-\the\wd0}\large\NOTE%
    },
]{theorem}
\declaretheorem[style=theorem]{theorem}
\declaretheorem[style=theorem]{example}

\declaretheoremstyle[
    within=section,
    spaceabove=10mm,
    spacebelow=3mm,
    headfont=\color{cyan}\normalfont,
    notefont=\normalfont,
    bodyfont=\itshape,
    headpunct=\newline\newline,
    %postheadspace={10pt},
    notebraces={}{},
    headformat={%
        \makebox[-10pt][r]{}\setbox0\hbox{\ }\hspace{-\the\wd0}\large\NAME%
    },
]{proof}
\let\proof\relax
\declaretheorem[style=proof,qed=\qedsymbol,name=Proof]{proof}
\declaretheorem[style=proof,qed=\qedsymbol,name=Solution]{solution}
```

Here's a MWE to go with it.

```
\documentclass{textbook}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\color{cyan}\itshape\LARGE}
  {\llap{\thesection}}
  {1em}
  {\sectiontitle}
  [\titleline{\color{cyan}\titlerule[1pt]}]

\begin{document}
\section*{Acknowledgement}% This section is not numbered
asdf
\chapter{test}
\end{document}
```

I can tell that the problem has to do with the #1 in my code. I've tried replacing with `\sectiontitle`, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The third mandatory argument to `\titleformat` is used for typesetting the number (when no * is used); the fourth is the separation between the number and the title, the fifth is used for typesetting the title. So what you want is

```
\titleformat{\section}
  {\color{cyan}\itshape\LARGE}
  {\llap{\thesection\ }}
  {0pt}
  {#1}
  [\titleline{\color{cyan}\titlerule[1pt]}]
```

This is the output of

```
\section*{Abc}
\section{Def}
```

[image]

*Never* use `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` in a class file, where they are already implicit at the start and end respectively.